# Unzip a file and store contents into a String, without writing to files

Tags: java

I need to grab a file from an FTP, then unzip the file to get the 3 files inside, and store them each as a String (and maybe put them into a String Array).

I'm later going to use a stored procedure in SQL to save these String Files to a DB. I cannot write to the FTP, so extracting them into files first is not an option.

What's the best way to unzip these files into each their own String in Java?

Comment: Use a ZipInputStream.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html

Comment: [`ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) could be useful

Comment: Does your JVM not have access to writing temp files? See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain `ZipInputStream` to an `InputStreamReader` then perhaps a `BufferedReader`.